# Whitening of some leaves of a potted key lime tree

Tags: indoors, leaves, citrus, office-gardening

I have a potted one-year-old-or so lime tree, which has looked quite healthy for the past two months or so (after recovering from a winter where it lost a lot of leaves due to overwatering).

Since the outside was really cold and it's on the ledge of the (closed) window of my office, I let the heater on during one night, in addition to the usual central heating -- so when I cam back the next day, my office was quite warm, maybe 27° C.

Later that day, I noticed that two leaves of the lime tree had edges that were whitening; after a few more days, it does not seem to spread to many leaves, but it currently had 3-4 leaves showng the same sort of whitening:

[image]

[image]

In terms of watering, I water this tree twice a week, and try not to overdo it; it's on the ledge of a window headed East, in an office in Manhattan (so, recently, it's been rather cold outside, roughly freezing temperatures; but my office stays at 18°-20° C).

Should I be worried? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Tell us more such as what type of soil, last fertilized and how much how long between fertilizing...are you using tap water and have the leaves browned, grayed at the tips earlier?  Please send a better photograph!

Comment: I am using tap water with a few drops of this: https://jet.com/product/detail/e79f6abe4aef442c80f533c49bfc0a33?jcmp=pla:ggl:nj_dur_win_home_garden_a3:lawn_garden_gardening_fertilizers_a3_other:na:PLA_348542940_24223016940_pla-161681866140:na:na:na:2&code=PLA15&gclid=Cj0KEQjw-73GBRCC7KODl9zToJMBEiQAj1Jgfx21dn95R4vrphtG18Mr4mq7zggr0liOdBgOHhQXTwEaAho28P8HAQ

Comment: (as for the browning -- I didn't nptice so. It happened really fast, less than a day)

Comment: The soil is some regular soil for pottef plants, IIRC; i haven't changed it since roughly November.

Comment: @stormy I borrowed someone else's cellphone to get better pictures.

Comment: check on the underside of the leaves for spider mites, a common problem.  They might cause the spotting on the leaves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the stuff you are using and combined with tap water way too much fertilizer/salts.  Dump your soil, wash out the pot and repot with new potting soil. No fertilizer for awhile.  Go get some bottled water and make sure your potting soil has no added fertilizers or water holding gels/sponges.  This margin stuff is pretty indicative of too much salt/fertilizer.

Doesn't look like insect damage to me but always look under the leaves for the little dudes or fine webbing...get a magnifier at least 10X.  This plant will be fine, but replace that salted soil, wash your pot (looks like clay, love clay but it will absorb salts...and show salts very quickly).