# Yellowing and falling of lime tree leaves

Tags: leaves, citrus

Following [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/31250/whitening-of-some-leaves-of-a-potted-key-lime-tree), I have re-potted my key lime tree into a bigger pot, changed the soil (using the "best" potting soil I could find around, i.e. one that does not hold water), and stopped using the [liquid plant food](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeEAD.jpg) I was adding to the water.

As before, I make sure to only water the plant when the soil looks dry (one or twice a week).

However, some of the leaves have recently been slightly curled (as one can see on the top left corner of the photo at the bottom of the post; and, more concerning, this morning when I arrived in my office I noticed that one of the leaves had fallen and was almost entirely yellow.

[image]

Being quite attached to the plants I have, this got me worried: should I be concerned? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two different things that could be going on. First, since you transplanted the plant to a different pot, the plant is going through a shock phase and adjusting to the new soil, pot, etc.  The other option, which I doubt since the other leaves look fine, is lack of fertilizer.  I have an outdoor lemon tree and it has yellow leaves as well but it is not a big deal. It gives me lemons all the time so other than fertilizing it with Citrus fertilizer and watering it, I don't do anything else.