# Key lime tree: white mush/mold (?) on the roots, and curling whitening leaves

Tags: citrus, roots, potting-soil

*This is a followup to [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/32570/yellowing-and-falling-of-lime-tree-leaves/32587), from a couple months ago. I tried yesterday to edit that question to include the followup, but it was not very well-received -- I assume it was not the right thing to do, so I'm starting a new one.*

While my citrus (key lime tree) is now making new leaves, some (3 or 4) of the "big" leaves are still looking unhealthy -- curling, with the edges turning dry and white.

I was not sure it was a big deal (after all, it *is* making new leaves), until I moved the pot today and saw this underneath:

[image]
[image]

I cleaned it and removed the white stuff from below, but now am pretty worried.

(I water the plant roughly 1-2 times a week, with nothing in the water -- I am no longer using "liquid plant food" as I used to every time ~2 months ago)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a terracotta pot. Due to the wicking action of these pots fertiliser salts can accumulate at the bottom and other locations.  They can burn roots so if there's that danger you can use a brush to clean the pot or a weak acid.

Comment: So, that'd not be actual mold, but instead leftover salts from a while back that eventually decided to team up at the bottom of the pot?

Comment: Yes, you over fertilised it so that made it happen faster.

Comment: Thank you. I'll monitor it closely to see if that white compound reappears.

Answer (score 2):

How bizarre, if it was me I'd just mix some fungicide with your next water to kill everything off, may just be some regular soil harmless stuff but I like to start knowing what's in the soil before adding things like microrysa into it.